# Javascript code to press CTRL+TAB?

Tags: javascript, tabs, ctrl

Since there's no way of moving to the next tab using javascript,

is there a code which presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> so it'd move to the next tab?

Comment: What do you mean by 'next tab'? Do you mean giving an element focus?

Comment: Why you want to move to new Tab? ypu mean instead of opening a new window?

Comment: Since you can't know what is in the next tab … why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **not possible**.

It would be a security risk for JavaScript to have the ability to control the browser in that way.

Imagine a malicious site (or a stupid developer) attempting to set the focus to the tab that contains their site every second...

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this. There is no way to switch between tabs using Javascript, or any kind of client scripting. That's as it should be. I don't want websites controlling the way I use my browser.

If you want to have tabs that you can switch between programmatically, you'll have to implement them yourself within the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send system level keys in javascript due to security reasons.